# Tagging: How to differentiate professional printing and everyday printing?

Tags: discussion, tagging

At the moment there's a single 'print' tag.

But I think there's a need to differentiate between

- printing the designer would do themselves for draft/preview/one-offs
- printing the designer would hand off to a printing company

They're quite different subjects, and generally use entirely different printing processes.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Think we need a 'print-design' tag as well.
Edit: And I've now retagged 'print' questions on design/layout specific to printed work, but not about printing itself as 'print-design'

Comment: Very good question!

Answer (score 4):

My personal opinion is that:

- `printing-desktop`
- `printing-press` (probably needs a better term, but can't think of a better oen right now)
- `print-design`

is sufficient to split the current `print` tag in a meaningful way.

Comment: I like this, but I still think `printing-press` ought to be split into sheetfed and web. My experience is that very different jobs are sent to those two, and a lot of context can be inferred from the type of press the job is being printed on.

Answer (score 4):

I think in the end, this will need to be addressed (and clarified) in the actual question. It's not unlike somebody asking a programming question about a specific command line tool, without specifying what operating system they're on. The first thing will be posting a comment to clarify that.

Alternatively, a tag suggestion:

```
professional-printing
```

meaning "Printing by qualified professionals in a printing company", as opposed to in-house printing done by the designer.

Comment: But what if the designer works for a company that also has in-house commercial printing capabilities? Would that be the same thing? Or how about the photographer that has a photo printer in-house for short-run jobs for clients? In that case "professional" can also mean "good enough".

Comment: @Philip yeah. Maybe this needs to be defined in the question rather than through tags.

Comment: i like the idea of two tags: "professional-printing" and "home-printing". Any clarification needed beyond that should be in the question. Its important to keep it somewhat simple

Answer (score 2):

How about a set of tags for the type of printing a document is intended for? A not-exhaustive list...

- `desktop-laser`
- `desktop-inkjet`
- `wide-format-inkjet`
- `offset-sheetfed`
- `offset-web`, `swop`

The designers in my circle of colleagues, almost always know that when a job is launched.

Comment: Perhaps "grande-format" or "digital-press" might be less ambiguous than "wide-format-inkjet," which could apply to everything from a 17" desktop printer to a 12 foot banner printer. Between presses like Indigo and the whopping banner and vinyl sign printers out there, there's quite a range, but I don't think those would need to be differentiated as tags.